# set background image of navigation's bar item

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

In my UINavigationController I have added an add button through the storyboard. My add button is the default "+" `UIBarButtonItem` from iOS/xcode. I would like to add a custom background image to the button. My codes is not working: the background image is not added.

```
-(void)addBackgroundToPlusSign
{
    UIImage *addBkg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_sign"];
    addBkg = [addBkg imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackButtonBackgroundImage:addBkg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:0];
}
```

I try calling the method in `viewDidLoad` and then in `viewWillAppear`. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the back button's background image on the right nav button... The right navigation button is not the *back* button. From the documentation:

> This modifier applies only to navigation bar back buttons and is
>   ignored by other buttons.

You want to use `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:`

Comment: aha! I was using `setBackButtonBackgroundImage` instead of `setBackgroundImage`. Bingo! thanks. Copy and paste error got me bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIImageView or button example:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 70, 30)];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_sign"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(your_method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

Comment: You are answering a different problem which I already know how to solve. What I want is to add a background to the button that comes with Xcode. If you think the plus sign is an easy case, then imagine one of the more elaborate buttons such as trash or camera.

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
UIBarButtonItem * addBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(btnHandler:)];

UIImage *addBkg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_sign"];
addBkg = [addBkg imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[addBtn setBackgroundImage:addBkg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:0];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBtn;
```

I think there used to be a bug where setting the background of an existing button didn't work until the view was re-added to the view stack. You could also try just doing:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
```